# Custom UITableViewCell with Optional UIImageView in a xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I created a custom UITableViewCell with an optional UIImageView in a xib. I created the constraints where a label's leading edge is attached the the imageView's trailing edge.

The image in the imageView is optional, and if I don't set the image I want to remove/hide the imageView and move the label over to the left. I tried to add and remove a constraint in code in layoutSubviews, but that broke the other constraints.

Am I on the right track here? I want it to behave like UITableViewCell native style of Value1/2 where if there is not an image set, than everything is moved to the left.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are on right track. The easy way to do that is you have to create an IBOutlet of your imageview widht constant. See image below.

[image: Imageview Width IBOutlet]

Then set your width constant to 0

```
if(// condition to check if imageview does not contain any image){
      _imgVwWidthConst.constant = 0;
}
```

Your label will automatically move to left as it has leading space to your imageview.

Comment: Thank you. Although may not feel like the correct solution, it worked. I would think that actually removing the imageView and updating all the constraints would be the correct solution. The only other thing I had to do was update a couple constraints to have their constant be greater than or equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two constraints one for the text label to the left edge of your view:

|<-(>=10)->[Label]...

|<-(10)->[ImageView]<-(10)->[Label]....

So if you want to hide the image all you can hide the image/deactivate the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to make this happen automatically because `UIImageView` maintains its size whether or not it has an image set or not.

One approach would be to leave the set up you currently have and update the label's constraint in your code to be `-yourImageView.bounds.size.width` when there is no image present. That would shift your label over when needed.